# Unable to fetch contacts from using google APIs

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

I am using Google Contacts API v3 for extracting google contacts.

I'm started with the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript for authentication and authorization. I have no problems with that part of the API access.

But after doing the auth part I have to fetch the google contacts(read only access would be fine for me). I am using gdata-javascript-client for the Google Contacts API v3. 
I am also referring google official doc and have copied the code and made the necessary changes to work for me.

My problem is,

1. Its not working. Its not entering to the registered call back function.
2. I have also tried using read only mode. But that too is not working.

There are two pieces of code that I am following, one for editable mode and other is read-only mode.

**Editable mode access:**

```
function handleAuthResult(authResult){
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        fetch_contacts_data(authResult);
    };
}

function auth() {
    var config = {
        'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
        'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, handleAuthResult);
}


function fetch_contacts_data(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token  + "&max-results=70000&alt=json" + "&callback=?",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            contacts = [];
            for (var i = 0, entry; entry = data.feed.entry[i]; i++) {
                var contact = {
                    'name' : entry['title']['$t'],
                    'id' : entry['id']['$t'],
                    'emails' : [],
                    'phoneNumber' : []
                };

                if (entry['gd$email']) {
                    var emails = entry['gd$email'];
                    for (var j = 0, email; email = emails[j]; j++) {
                        contact['emails'].push(email['address']);
                    }
                }
                if (entry['gd$phoneNumber']) {
                    var phoneNumber = entry['gd$phoneNumber'];
                    for (var j = 0, phone; phone = phoneNumber[j]; j++) {
                        contact['phoneNumber'].push(phone['$t']);

                    }
                }
                if (!contact['name']) {
                    contact['name'] = contact['emails'][0] || "<Unknown>";
                }
                contacts.push(contact);
            }
            numContacts = contacts.length;
            friend_list_json_str = '';
            for(var j=0;j<numContacts;j++) {
                name = (contacts[j])['name'];
                emails = (contacts[j])['emails'];
                phone = (contacts[j])['phoneNumber'];
                email_list= '';
                phone_list= '';
                for(var k=0;k<emails.length;k++) {
                    email_list += '"'+emails[k] + '",' ;
                }
                email_list = email_list.substring(0, email_list.length -1)

                for(var k=0;k<phone.length;k++) {
                    phone_list = '"'+phone[k] + '",';
                }
                phone_list += phone_list.substring(0, phone_list.length -1)

                friend_json_str = '';
                friend_json_str += '{"name":"'+name + '",';
                friend_json_str += '"emails":['+email_list+'],';
                friend_json_str += '"phoneNumber":['+phone_list+']' ;
                friend_json_str += '},';
                friend_list_json_str += friend_json_str;
            }
            friend_list_json_str = friend_list_json_str.substring(0, friend_list_json_str.length - 1);

            var user_data = get_user_data();
            var len = user_data.length;
            user_data = user_data.substring(0, len - 2);
            user_data += friend_list_json_str + ']}';
            data = "invite_data="+ user_data;
            url = '/invite';
            var posting = $.post( url, data );

            posting.done(function( response_data ) {
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Read Only access:**

```
function auth() {
    var config = {
        'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
        };
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, handleAuthResult);
}
```

NOTE: rest of the code is same as above

In both the cases the ajax call is failing,

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token  + "&max-results=70000&alt=json" + "&callback=?",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
```

Can someone please tell me why this code is not working?

Comment: Remember your client id must be kept safe and secure at all times. I have edited your question and removed it for you.

Comment: Remove ` + "&callback=?"` from the ajax request. I think that is triggering a JSONP response instead of using your success callback. And client_ids can be considered public, they are included in the client side JS after all. It's server keys/secrets you have to keep secret.

Comment: did you meant to say I have to handle it differently, other than cb mechanism?could you suggest me to way to handle jSONP responses...

Answer (score 0):

You're blocked by your browser's popup blocker.

Try to call the `auth()` method after clicking on a button, it should work.

To void this issue, you need to :

1. First, attempt a call to `gapi.auth.authorize` with the parameter `{immediate:true}`. It will try to obtain a token in background if the user already gave his permission.
2. If it fails, display a button to the user for authentication. When the user clicks on it, call `gapi.auth.authorize` with the parameter `{immediate:false}`.

Comment: Hi David, it did not worked for me..Upon further investigation I found that I am getting response data but somehow the registered callback is not getting called..